# How to hide country and city label?

Tags: openlayers

Now I'm using OpenLayers to integrate OpenStreetMap into my web. Besides, I want to hide/remove all the labels on map (country, city, road, lake...).

How can I do that without establishing my own map server?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change anything on the tiles from openstreetmap.org.

But you may look out for other tile providers who use Openstreetmap data.

Stamen has some real nice maps:

http://maps.stamen.com/#toner/12/37.7691/-122.3510